# Scout SmartField suggestions from Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, service, drilldown, eclipse-scout

I am working in Scout and need SmartField. For this I need to set up lookup for suggestions.

I see the example with creating Lookup Call and than implement in Lookup Service `getConfiguredSqlSelect`

but I use Hibernate to work with classes, so my question is how to connect Smart field with Hibernate object filled service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new lookup call according to [1] with the following differences:

1. don't select AbstractSqlLookupService as a lookup servic super type, but AbstractLookupService
2. in the associated lookup service you now need to implement getDataByAll, getDataByKey, and getDataByText

to illustrate the following snippet should help:

```
public class TeamLookupService extends AbstractLookupService<String> implements ITeamLookupService {

  private List<ILookupRow<String>> m_values = new ArrayList<>();

  public TeamLookupService() {
    m_values.add(new LookupRow<String>("CRC", "Costa Rica"));
    m_values.add(new LookupRow<String>("HON", "Honduras"));
    m_values.add(new LookupRow<String>("MEX", "Mexico"));
    m_values.add(new LookupRow<String>("USA", "USA"));
  }

  @Override
  public List<? extends ILookupRow<String>> getDataByAll(ILookupCall<String> call) throws ProcessingException {
    return m_values;
  }

  @Override
  public List<? extends ILookupRow<String>> getDataByKey(ILookupCall<String> call) throws ProcessingException {
    List<ILookupRow<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (ILookupRow<String> row : m_values) {
      if (row.getKey().equals(call.getKey())) {
        result.add(row);
      }
    }

    return result;
  }
  ...
```

[1] https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Tutorial/4.0/Minicrm/Lookup_Calls_and_Lookup_Services#Create_Company_Lookup_Call